# Choose only required data from PHP - SQL Group by array function

Tags: php, sql, arrays

The following SQL PHP code shows count of country from database and displays it in a table.
Here is the code

```
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT country,COUNT(*)
FROM data_able
GROUP BY country') as $row) {    $array = array();
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
Here is the result
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee2Yn.png)

I would like to use the data as `$country1` and `$count1`.
For example `$country1` will output "Andorra" and `$country5` will be "India".
and `$count5` should give "25" as result. How can I do that ?

Comment: You _shouldn't_ do that, because "numbered" variable names are bad. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to declare variables dynamicly:

```php
$array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

foreach ($array as $i) {
    ${'country' . $i} = $i;
}

echo $country2;
```

You just need to iterate through your query results with keeping some index on variable suffix (in your case a number).

```php
// create a dynamic variables
$result = $dbh->query('SELECT country,COUNT(*) FROM data_able GROUP BY country');
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    ${'country' . $i} = $row['country'];
    ${'count' . $i} = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $i++;
}

// example how to use them
$i = 1;
foreach($result as $row) {
    $array = array();
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . ${'country' . $i} . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .${'count' . $i} . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: it will be so great if you can show a real example. I have no idea what to do with `$i`, I am new with these...

Comment: @Shamip I've edited the post, check if the code suits your requirements